# Two circles and the max length of a line through their intersection

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles

Consider two circles and their intersections A and B. Let r be a line through A, and call C and D the other intersections between r and the two circles. Prove that CD is of maximum length iff r is parallel to the line that passes through the center of both circles. No calculus allowed (this is a tenth grade problem).

My initial approach was to draw r and r', one parallel one not, and try to use the triangular inequality. This doesn't work because while one segment (say, AD) decreases the other (AC) increases.

Trying to use algebraic formulas to compute the lengths as a function of the radius of both circles gets messy, and given the context (this is a problem from a tenth grade textbook) I doubt this is necessary. There's bound to be a simple geometric solution I'm missing.

I tried to see if an additional assumption of equal radius for both circles simplified things or led to some insight but it didn't look like it. I tried to see if considering the triangles formed by r with the line through the centers could help, but it felt far off.

The thing that felt the closest to a solution was the idea of considering the chords AC and AD as being tied to the angles on the circumference, and somehow find angles that geometrically sum to something (either adjacent or part of some triangle). There's still the problem of having a different radius on the two circles, and even then, how would that turn into a condition on r being parallel?

I'm pretty stumped here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Sure, here you go. I don't think it's gonna help much but if it's to make sure I at least tried to do something, well, I've been wracking my brain on this thing for two days so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Consider arbitrary line IJ. Drop perpendiculars from O and O', they meet IJ at G and H. Trapezoid OGHO' is right angled at H , so $OO'>GH=\frac{IG}{2}$. you want IJ be maximum, This means trapezoid must become rectangle such that  $GH=OO'=EF=\frac{CD}2$, that is G and H become coincident on F and E resprctively. where quadrilateral OEFO' is rectangle and $OO'=FE$, that is CD must be parallel with OO'.

Comment: Thanks! Drawing a parallel to r through O allows you to phrase the solution in terms of triangle inequality too, which I suspect is the idea behind the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using a little calculus and trigonometry.
The triangle $\triangle{M_1M_2A}$ is fixed. Line DF rotates around A over an angle $\varphi$ which is the only variable. Length DF can be easily expressed in terms of $\varphi$. To get an optimum, we differentiate and establish that $\frac{sin(\varphi+\alpha)}{r_2}=\frac{sin(\varphi)}{r_1}$[image]
Now apply the sine rule in $\triangle{M_1 M_2 A}$. This results in
$\frac{sin(\epsilon+\alpha)}{r_2}=\frac{sin(\epsilon)}{r_1}$
Therefore the maximum length DF is reached when $\epsilon=\varphi$
Which implies that DF is parallel to the line passing through the center of both circles.